# Store data calculated or calculate in real time stats - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, statistics

I have the following courses database, each time a user answers a question of a course this is stored in the "Answerings" table, where the UserID and Questionid and QuestionOptionsID are saved, the number of questions depends on the course, can go Between 5 to 50 questions per courses, and each course can have 5 to 500 users, the system is built in Rails

```
Users       Stats         Answerings     Questions      QuestionOptions    Courses
---------   -------       -------        -------        -------            ------- 
id          id            id             id             id                 id
fullname    user_id       user_id        course_id      question_id        name
            course_id     question_id    description    option_text
            points        q_options_id   points         is_correct
            views
            calculation1
            calculation2
            calculation3
```

Then this data must show them in a report per course, where I show all the users who have responded, calculating the total points obtained, the number of questions repeated, and as well as I must calculate 3 more fields related to the business logic of the Company, which are generated with the number of correct and incorrect answers and the user's knowledge.

When the table has less than 50 users, the generation of the report is slow, because each user calculates 4 to 5 fields.

My solution was to create a table called "Stats", which is 1 to 1 with the "Users" table, this information is calculated at the time the person is answered by a service on Background.

This impacts significantly when the reports are generated by courses, because it no longer calculates 5 to 6 fields, only calculates the "STATS" table and only shows the field already calculated previously.

The question is this solution is correct?, Or should I optimize without using the Table "Stats"

Answer (score 2):

Storing the calculated total could be thought of as caching. Caching calculations like this means you have to start dealing with keeping the calculation up to date and worrying about when it isn't. In the long run, that pattern can result in a lot of work. On the flip side, always calculating the total means you will always have a fresh calculation to work with.

I've seen folks store calculations to address performance issues, when calculating is taking a long time due to its complexity or the complexity of the query its based off of. That's a good reason to start thinking about caching results like this.

Have you tried running a few queries to discover how many (if any) pre-computed values are wrong or outdated? This would have much more weight than vague "it's faster/no, it doesn't count" discussions which rarely see a clear winner.

But it can give you some pros. For example if you have lots of users and the users call those values calculating a lot then it could be more winnable strategy to calculate them once in a while. It will save your server resources.

Your real question now is "What will be more effective for you? Calculate values each time or calculate them once in a while and store in DB?"

Comment: interesting... yes, I definitely will need to call those values a lot in order to display their progress

Comment: @zetanova In order to keep accurate auditing you must make a record of each response that affects the points and values of the users' account. This means that you can calculate the points and other values dynamically, however for reasons of performance, you would also have to store them in the table.